# Swap all elements in a list in python 3.4

Tags: python, list

Let's say my list looks like this:

```
myList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']
```

And I want the outcome to look like this:

```
One, Eight, Two, Seven, Three, Six, Four, Five
```

What would be the simplest way to go about this?

Comment: What's the expected output if you exclude `Eight` from the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import deque

myList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']


def swap(items):
    items = deque(items)
    while items:
        yield items.popleft()
        try:
            yield items.pop()
        except IndexError:
            pass

print list(swap(myList))
```

Edit: Now non destructive and copes with uneven length lists

Edit: using deque so its memory efficient

Comment: Beautiful answer, didn't knew you could pop any element from the list, python is amazing, you don't need the "-1" though since by default you pop the last item.

Comment: Its now non destructive and can cope with uneven lists

Comment: popping from the front of a list is a needlessly intensive operation. Try instead `yield items[0]`, `for i in range(1, len(items)//2)` and `yield items[i]` and `items[-i]`, then account for odd-length lists as a special case. This will also keep you from having to store two copies of the list in memory, which could be important for huge lists.

Comment: Changed to use deque so its memory efficient

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, this would create a new list with the required ordering.

```
myList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']
i = 0
new_list = []
while i < len(myList)/2:
  new_list.append(myList[i])
  i += 1
  new_list.append(myList[-i])
print ', '.join(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']

z=[x for x in myList if myList.index(x)>=len(myList)/2]
print zip(myList,reversed(z))
```

You can try this.

Comment: `z = myList[len(myList)//2:]`, though this list needs to be flattened first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner, you can look at:

```
final = [el for zipped in zip(lst[:4], reversed(lst[4:])) for el in zipped]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to solve the problem that do not require exception handling, loading the input list into a spare data structure just to destroy it. They do this by computing the midpoint of the list and cleanly knowing whether they're dealing with an odd-length list:

```
def interleave(l):
    """
    Non-destructive front-and-back iterleave of list items.
    """
    midpoint, odd_length = divmod(len(l), 2)
    for i in range(midpoint):
        yield l[i]
        yield l[-i-1]
    if odd_length:
        yield l[midpoint]
```

Or:

```
def interleave2(l):
    """
    Non-destructive front-and-back iterleave of list items.
    Uses zip and reversed generators and list slicing.
    Arguably more "Pythonic," but depends on more in-flight 
    infrastructure and consumes more memory.
    """
    midpoint, odd_length = divmod(len(l), 2)
    for front, back in zip(l[:midpoint], reversed(l[midpoint:])):
        yield front
        yield back
    if odd_length:
        yield l[midpoint]
```

And here's a little impromptu test harness to confirm the results are correct:

```
myList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']
myListAnswer = ['One', 'Eight', 'Two', 'Seven', 'Three', 'Six', 'Four', 'Five']

answers = {}
for algorithm in [interleave, interleave2]:
    print()
    print(algorithm.__name__, "\n", "=" * len(algorithm.__name__), "\n")

    # test the simple case
    assert list(algorithm(myList)) == myListAnswer

    # test a number of list sizes
    for j in range(11):
        # run algorithm and show inputs and outputs
        l = list(range(j))
        print("size:", j)
        print("list:", l)
        answer = list(algorithm(l))
        print("answer:", answer)

        # check assertions
        prev_answer = answers.setdefault(j, answer)
        assert len(l) == len(answer)
        assert l == sorted(answer)
        assert answer == prev_answer
        print("--")
```

This yields:

```
interleave 
========== 

size: 0
list: []
answer: []
--
size: 1
list: [0]
answer: [0]
--
size: 2
list: [0, 1]
answer: [0, 1]
--
size: 3
list: [0, 1, 2]
answer: [0, 2, 1]
--
size: 4
list: [0, 1, 2, 3]
answer: [0, 3, 1, 2]
--
size: 5
list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
answer: [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
--
size: 6
list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
answer: [0, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
--
size: 7
list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
answer: [0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
--
size: 8
list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
answer: [0, 7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
--
size: 9
list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
answer: [0, 8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
--
size: 10
list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
answer: [0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
--

# ...and continues on with similar output for interleave2 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Slice:

```
>>> result = list(myList)
>>> result[::2] = myList[:4]
>>> result[::-2] = myList[4:]
>>> result
['One', 'Eight', 'Two', 'Seven', 'Three', 'Six', 'Four', 'Five']
```

The first assignment could be replaced by anything that creates a list of the correct length, then the first 4 elements of myList become every second element of the result and the last 4 elements are every second element going backwards from the end.

and of course if you want the output without the brackets:

```
>>> print(', '.join(result))
One, Eight, Two, Seven, Three, Six, Four, Five
```

If you don't mind splatting the original list you can do it all in one line:

```
>>> myList[::2], myList[::-2] = myList[:4], myList[4:]
>>> myList
['One', 'Eight', 'Two', 'Seven', 'Three', 'Six', 'Four', 'Five']
```